# Menu vertical colapasable queda muy chico

Tags: css

busque un tutorial para crear un menu vertical que se esconda pero me qued muy corto de altura, probe poner un height de 100% pero no lo logro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo de html es:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="exit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

        <nav id="sidebar">
            <!-- Sidebar Header -->
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>GESTION WEB</div>
            

            <!-- Sidebar Links -->
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <ul>
    <li class="dropdown"><a  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      <span>ABM</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=cliente&action=index">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>Cliente</span>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=articulo&action=index">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i><span>Articulo</span>
        </a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.php?controller=marca&action=index">Marca</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?controller=categoria&action=index">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?controller=subcategoria&action=index">SubCategoria</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=proveedor&action=index"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>Proveedores</span></a></a></li>
       <!--  <li ><a href="index.php?controller=envase&action=todos">Envases</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=medida&action=index">Medidas</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=canilla&action=index">Canillas</a></li> --!>
       <li ><a href="index.php?controller=user&action=index"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>Usuarios</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li class="dropdown"><a  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Nuevo Comp.</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=ticket&action=index">Ticket</a></li>
   <li ><a href="index.php?controller=facturaa&action=index">Factura</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Estado de cajas</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="">Chequera</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=caja&action=gasto">Nuevo Gasto</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=caja&action=index">Cerrar caja</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=cliente&action=cuenta">Cuenta Corriente</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=caja&action=indexgrande">Caja Grande</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Posnet</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li class="dropdown"><a  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Nueva Venta</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=venta&action=index">Canilla</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=venta&action=cerrado">Producto</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </li>
<li class="dropdown"><a  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Compra de stock</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=stock&action=index">Productos</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=stock&action=indexb">Barril</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=stock&action=canilla">Cambio de canilla</a></li>
      </ul>
    
    </li>
  </ul>





      <input type="hidden" id="cajero" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])){
        
        echo $_SESSION['userid'];
      }?>"/> 
       <input type="hidden" id="sesion" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION["idsesion"])){
        
        echo $_SESSION['idsesion'];
      }?>"/> 
       <input type="hidden" id="inicio" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION["inicio"])){
        
        echo $_SESSION['inicio'];
      }?>"/> 

        </nav>

        <div id="content">
     
            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="navbar-btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </button>
        <div>
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Salir" id="exit"/>
<label>Nombre..<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo $_SESSION['username'];}?></label>
<label>Rol..<?php if (isset($_SESSION['rol'])){echo $_SESSION['rol'];}?></label>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Y el CSS:

```css
#sidebarCollapse {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

#sidebarCollapse span {
    width: 80%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background: #555;
    transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.810, -0.330, 0.345, 1.375);
}
#sidebarCollapse span:first-of-type {
    /* rotate first one */
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
}
#sidebarCollapse span:nth-of-type(2) {
    /* second one is not visible */
    opacity: 0;
}
#sidebarCollapse span:last-of-type {
    /* rotate third one */
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, -1px);
}
#sidebarCollapse.active span {
    /* no rotation */
    transform: none;
    /* all bars are visible */
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    perspective: 1500px; 
}

#sidebar {
    
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.945, 0.020, 0.270, 0.665);
    transform-origin: center left; /* Set the transformed position of sidebar to center left side. */
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
    transform: rotateY(100deg); /* Rotate sidebar vertically by 100 degrees. */
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Reversing the behavior of the sidebar: 
       it'll be rotated vertically and off canvas by default, 
       collapsing in on toggle button click with removal of 
       the vertical rotation.   */
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
        transform: rotateY(100deg);
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
        transform: none;
    }

    /* Reversing the behavior of the bars: 
       Removing the rotation from the first,
       last bars and reappear the second bar on default state, 
       and giving them a vertical margin */
    #sidebarCollapse span:first-of-type,
    #sidebarCollapse span:nth-of-type(2),
    #sidebarCollapse span:last-of-type {
        transform: none;
        opacity: 1;
        margin: 5px auto;
    }

    /* Removing the vertical margin and make the first and last bars rotate again when the sidebar is open, hiding the second bar */
    #sidebarCollapse.active span {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse.active span:first-of-type {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
    }
    #sidebarCollapse.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse.active span:last-of-type {
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, -1px);
    }
}
body {font-family:sans-serif;width: 100%;margin:0; 
 padding:0;text-align: left;position: relative;margin-right: auto;margin-left:auto;color: black; }
/*tablas del sistema*/
table {     font-family: Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 14px;  margin: 0;left: 10%;  width: 100%; text-align: left;   border-collapse: collapse; }
table tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #81a2ac;font-weight: bold; font-size:14px;}

table tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #d6ecf2;font-weight:bold}
th {     font-size: 14px;     font-weight: normal;     padding: 8px;     background: #b9c9fe;
    border-top: 4px solid #aabcfe;    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; color: #039; }

td {    padding: 8px;        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #669;    border-top: 1px solid transparent; }

tr:hover td { background: #d0dafd; color: #339; }
.totales{
    float:right; width: 20%    
 
        
    
}
select {color:blue;}
.contenedor {position:relative;  width:965px; height:1000px; margin:0px auto; text-align:center;}
.cabecera{width:965px; height:150px;}
.cuerpo {width:965px; height:300px;font-size: 20px;}
.pie {width:965px; height:150px;}
table.precios tr{font-size: 30px;}
div.panel-heading{font-size:16px; font-weight: bold;}
table.canilla tr{background-color: white;text-align: center;font-size:20px;}
table.canilla tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #d6ecf2;font-weight:bold; font-size:20px;}
table.canilla th{background-color: yellowgreen; color: white; font-size: 16px; text-align: center;}
    
select:focus{
    border-color: blue;
}
label.titulo{
    font-family: sans-serif;

color: blue;


}
.totales th{
    
    width: 50%;
}
caption {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
color: black;
background:#d9edc2;
border:4px solid #b2ce96;

}
```

Osea quiero que me queden las palabras del menu dentro de un recuadro y que ocupe hasta abajo, la verdad no se porque sale asi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El height: 100% solo funciona dentro de 1 elemento con altura definida, en su lugar para este caso usa :

```
height: 100vh;
```

que te da el alto del viewport height, es decir la altura de la pantalla.

Comment: funciono..pero las opciones quedan arriba amontonadas, me gustaria que se distribuyan como son en la mayoria de las paginas..perdona mi ignorancia

Comment: Eso ya depende del padding de tu lista https://codepen.io/memoadian/pen/WLWERV generalmente todos los menus sidebar quedan con las opciones del menu arriba, y conforme pones más llenan  todo el espacio, si son muy pocas aumentas los margenes o el padding para que se vean mejor distribuidas. Demo de un sidebar https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/

Comment: Entiendo..pero me queda el texto como enlace en vez de oscurecerce la zona entera digamos..no s esi ves en la imagen del post.

Comment: Entonces agrega el padding al enlace, en lugar de al li. Para que agarre el enlace debes poner le display block, pero bueno esas ya son cuestiones de otra indole, te dejo el demo que hice modificado, espero te ayude. https://codepen.io/memoadian/pen/WLWERV

Comment: Tambien funciono mucas gracias